# Can a Transaction be Committed Without a Corresponding BEGIN TRAN in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, commit

In SQL Server we have a series of stored procedures that run to process data which are called from a wrapper procedure. Towards the end of this process it executes a procedure that summarizes the data and dumps it into tables in a separate database. Data is constantly changing while customers are viewing it so we use the (nolock) hint to prevent locking of the tables. I know this isn't best practice but unfortunately I didn't create the process and I have to live with it. The issue I'm running into, as I'm sure you'd expect, is that sometimes it is inserting dirty data into the summary tables. Is there a way to commit the new records from the procedures prior to mine before it executes my procedure when there is no BEGIN TRAN? Another note: I cannot use BEGIN TRAN.

Comment: If you are pulling data from dirty reads that you don't want to insert into another table the solution is to stop using nolock.

Comment: Don't use `NOLOCK` if you don't want dirty reads. Period.

Comment: Not only is using `NoLock` not best practice, it's compromising your data's integrity entirely because double reads, and dirty reads are very much a thing.

Comment: Better suggestion, start removing the `NoLock` hints and start looking into db indexes instead, this will likely offset the performance hit of scrapping `NoLock`

Comment: For some good reading on all of the suggestions here about NOLOCK, here's a good article (that I'm a little surprised @SeanLange didn't link to in his comment). [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: @EricBrandt yeah I do like to send people to that one. :)

Comment: I'm reading the Bad habits article now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would also remove NOLOCK as it is especially dangerous in this kind of highly concurrent scenario.

If you really can't use BEGIN TRAN then I think you will just have to remove the NOLOCK and let SQL Server take care of things, which is generally a good idea anyway.
Focus on tuning the SQL in all the processes involved so its as quick as possible and that will at least minimise blocking.

If you can, I would suggest having each stored procedure use its own transaction BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT to insert data into the "intermediate" tables.  IF you want them to ROLLBACK for any reason I guess you should consider passing out a flag so the parent procedure can avoid any further processing.  You will be wanting these statements to be well tuned so that they are not locking for any longer than needed , so as others have suggested, look at indexes.